# How to relate Software with my Server CI in ServiceNow? Best Practice

Tags: servicenow, itil

Currently I keep track of all my servers in SNOW. Now I want to go further and keep track of my installed software. Would my Software be a CI? Or what is the best practice to keep track of my installed software?
I don't have a discovery license.

Usecase:
When my Kaspersky Software needs a license upgrade I want to flag all servers in SNOW which are using Kaspersky. How should Kaspersky be related to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question!

There is in fact, a specific module for this sort of thing, called **Software Asset Management**. This is a **Plugin** for ServiceNow, which you can activate by following [these steps](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-it-service-management/page/product/asset-management/task/t_ActivatingSoftwareAssetManagement.html).

To answer your question simply though, in general you would [add the software](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-it-service-management/page/product/asset-management/task/t_ManagingSoftwareModels.html) your organization has or might have licenses for, to the **Software Models** table (cmdb_software_product_model).

Once that's in your CMDB, you'll want to [create software license records](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-it-service-management/page/product/asset-management/task/t_AddANewSoftwareLicense.html) in **Software Asset > Software Licenses.**. (or the alm_license table). Here, the "rights" field is the main important one, as it indicates the number of license rights you have for a given piece of software. Then, by defining **entitlements**, you can [define the people or machines](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-it-service-management/page/product/asset-management/task/t_CreatSWLicenseEntitlemnt.html) that [consume](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-it-service-management/page/product/asset-management/task/t_EntitleLicenConfigItem.html) these entitlements.

Comment: No problem Ray! The book should be out in just another month or two, I'm hoping! I'm finishing up my final chapter this week, and then we just have to do technical review and some editing!